# Finding $O(ab)$ when $O(a)$ and $O(b)$ are given in non abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a non abelian group. If $ a$ and $b$ $\in$ $G$ and $O(a) = 3$ and $O(b) = 4$. Then what is the order of the element $ab?$

Now Since $O(a)= 3$ and $O(b)= 4$ , $O(G)$ must be of the form $12.n$ for some $n \in N$. therefore $O(ab)$ should divide $12.n.$

I dont know how to proceed from here...please give me a hint to solve this problem

$a) 6 \quad b) 12 \quad c)$ of $12k$ for some $k \in R \quad d)$ need not be finite

Comment: Why should the order be divisible by $12$?

Comment: Presumably $G$ is assumed finite?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Langrange's theorem

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury This does not follow from Lagrange (and it is in fact false).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The order of a subgroup divides the order of the group. Since $O(a)$ is 3 we can form a subgroup ${e, a^2, a^3}$. Same can be said about $b$. So $O(ab)$ must divide $12n$

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury But there is no reason why the subgroup generated by $ab$ should contain $a$ or $b$ or any of their powers.

Comment: Sorry...i will add the choices...given in the question

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think that the question (on careful reading) is talking about the order of the group, assumed finite, not of the element $ab$ at that stage in the argument.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The order of any element in this group should divide $12n$. There is nothing special about the powers of $a$ and $b$

Comment: If G is Finite...then O(a) = 3 and O(b) =4 divides O(G)..So O(G) should be 12.k...Thats the reason. Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: Your comment on the order of the group assumes that it is finite, but the suggested answers imply that you cannot make this assumption unless you justify it. If the group is infinite, its order is not of the form $12n$ with $n\in \mathbb N$

Comment: Yes you are right...What if G is Finite..?

Comment: I thank everyone for your valuable comment guys...

Answer (score 5):

This question does not have a determinate answer, not even if $G$ is assumed finite. In $S_7$, the order of $(1\,2\,3)(4\,5\,6\,7)$ is 12, while the order of $(1\,2\,3)(1\,2\,3\,4) = (1\,3\,4\,2)$ is 4.

Comment: Also $(123)(345)=(12345)$ shows that the product of two elements of order $3$ need not be divisible by $3$.